# Error when storing the images (data) in the repository and training the model [Google Colab]

Tags: python, file-upload, google-colaboratory, image-classification

First I tried to download using my GitHub as my images are stored there, however when I run the code it doesn't show that it has downloaded the images

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IcMW.png)

But when I give a print on the screen it shows the path that supposedly the images were saved.
Then I try to do the training using the images, but I get two errors:

1 ° Traceback (most recent last call)

2 ° Could not find directory /root/.keras/datasets/dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA70T.png)

I have no idea how to solve the 1st problem and the 2nd I don't understand why it didn't find the files.I will be very grateful if someone can help me

Note: I'm not experienced in programming and this is the first time I use Google Colab.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)